# Set attribute to Ember Component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to set the `draggable` attribute to the component `div` itself.

In previous versions of ember (pre 1.13) I am used to use the `attributeBindings` property. But since 1.13 this property seems to be deprecated.

There are new lifecyle hooks for components (http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_component-lifecycle-hooks) but that didnt helped me either.

```
didInitAttrs() {
    this.set('draggable', true);
}
```

What is the prefered way to achieve this behavior?

**UPDATE**

In the meantime this is my solution:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  draggable: true,

  willInsertElement() {
    this.set('element.draggable', this.get('draggable'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AttributeBindings` are not deprecated or you would get warnings when using them with components.

The property just happens to be inherited from ember views which are going away in 2.4 (long time away), but it doesn't mean the inherited interfaces on the components will go away without any deprecation notice. So just keep using `attributeBindings`.

Comment: You are right, I have no idea how I got there. (-I am pretty sure I read about it in the emberjs blog-)